# Dynamic parameters not sql types Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, record, dynamic-programming, rowtype

im trying to do something like this:

```
create function getData(r1 IN TABLE1%ROWTYPE,col1 string, valor OUT string)RETURN string AS

  instruccion VARCHAR2(500);
  valor VARCHAR(200);
BEGIN

     valor := r1.col1;

  return valor;

END getData;
```

A procedure that takes as parameters a record and the name of the column and give back the value and:

```
CREATE procedure p1 as

   vData VARCHAR2(80);
   v1 VARCHAR2(80);
   vValue VARCHAR2(80);

   inst VARCHAR2(500);

  CURSOR vTable2 IS SELECT * FROM TABLE2;

  CURSOR vTable1 IS SELECT * FROM TABLE1;

BEGIN

  --A cursor for the table with the data
  FOR d1 IN vTable1
  LOOP 
          --A cursor for the table that store the name of the columns of the    table 1 
          FOR v1 IN vTable2
          LOOP
            --get the table1 column name
            vData :=  v1.table2Col1;
            --calls the procedure that gives back the value of that record on the column name is stored in VData
            inst := 'begin getData(:d1, :vData, :vValue ); end;';


            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE inst USING in d1 , vData, OUT vValue;

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vValue);

          END LOOP;

  END LOOP;

END p1;
```

So in summary i just want to have a table that store the names of the table1 in table2, because I want the procedure to work with any table with the name table1, this code gives me the error "expression have to be of SQL types" for the parameters of the dynamic block and i understand it but can figure out a new way to do it. I have tried a lot of things but I'm kind of new in oracle and I really would appreciated the help.

Comment: Why are you using `execute immediate`? Why don't you just call the function `getData(d1,vData,vValue);`?

Comment: No need of dynamic SQL here. See my answer.

Comment: It is not clear what you try to achieve, however have a look at [DBMS_SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm). But in many cases you don't need dynamic SQL.

Comment: Are you able to compile your function `getData`?

Comment: Hi, no the function getData says that the component col1 must be declared i assume that is because col1 its not the name of the column but is a variable that contains the name of the column. @Polppan

Comment: thanks @LalitKumarB but in your example you know that the column name is 'ename' what i need is to always be able to change the column name

Comment: I still don't understand. If you want the column to be dynamic as well,then use the same logic as I have demonstrated, but make the column name dynamic. But then, you need to take care of all such places where you reference the column.

Comment: Im sorry but i don't understand how can i do it if i don't know how many columns the table has or what their names are, without passing a not SQL type as parameter

Answer (score 0):

> inst := 'begin getData(:d1, :vData, :vValue ); end;';
>
> EXECUTE IMMEDIATE inst USING in d1 , vData, OUT vValue;

I don't see any reason you need to use **dynamic SQL** here. All you want is to to pass **%ROWTYPE** parameter and process it. %ROWTYPE is treated as a **RECORD**, which you would be able to use in the PL/SQL program.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2    FUNCTION func(
  3        i_dept IN NUMBER,
  4        i_emp_rec  IN emp%rowtype )
  5      RETURN VARCHAR2
  6    IS
  7    BEGIN
  8      RETURN 'DEPTNO = ' || i_dept || ' ENAME = ' || i_emp_rec.ename;
  9    END;
 10  /

Function created.

SQL>
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_deptno dept.deptno%type;
  3    cur sys_refcursor;
  4    v_ecur sys_refcursor;
  5    v_emp emp%rowtype;
  6  BEGIN
  7    OPEN cur FOR SELECT d.deptno,
  8    CURSOR
  9      ( SELECT e.* FROM emp e WHERE e.deptno = d.deptno
 10      ) e FROM dept d;
 11    LOOP
 12      FETCH cur INTO v_deptno, v_ecur;
 13      EXIT
 14    WHEN cur%notfound;
 15      LOOP
 16        FETCH v_ecur INTO v_emp;
 17        EXIT
 18      WHEN v_ecur%notfound;
 19        dbms_output.put_line(func(v_deptno,v_emp));
 20      END LOOP;
 21      CLOSE v_ecur;
 22    END LOOP;
 23    CLOSE cur;
 24  END;
 25  /
DEPTNO = 10 ENAME = CLARK
DEPTNO = 10 ENAME = KING
DEPTNO = 10 ENAME = MILLER
DEPTNO = 20 ENAME = SMITH
DEPTNO = 20 ENAME = JONES
DEPTNO = 20 ENAME = SCOTT
DEPTNO = 20 ENAME = ADAMS
DEPTNO = 20 ENAME = FORD
DEPTNO = 30 ENAME = ALLEN
DEPTNO = 30 ENAME = WARD
DEPTNO = 30 ENAME = MARTIN
DEPTNO = 30 ENAME = BLAKE
DEPTNO = 30 ENAME = TURNER
DEPTNO = 30 ENAME = JAMES

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```